# Google Docs and xml reading

Tags: javascript, xml, google-docs

i've working code(below) to read xml in google docs. It works greate if xml looks like this(part i'm interested in):

```
<row orderID="4452813795" charID="96255569" stationID="60011752" volEntered="1" volRemaining="1" minVolume="1" orderState="0" typeID="11134" range="32767" accountKey="1002" duration="90" escrow="0.00" price="20000.00" bid="0" issued="2016-02-28 02:05:29"/>
```

What i want is volRemaining value and my code returns 1. But if xml looks like this:

```
<row orderID="4452813795" charID="96255569" stationID="60011752" volEntered="1" volRemaining="1" minVolume="1" orderState="0" typeID="11134" range="32767" accountKey="1002" duration="90" escrow="0.00" price="20000.00" bid="0" issued="2016-02-28 02:05:29"/>
<row orderID="4452814032" charID="96255569" stationID="60011752" volEntered="1" volRemaining="1" minVolume="1" orderState="0" typeID="11134" range="32767" accountKey="1002" duration="90" escrow="0.00" price="20000.00" bid="0" issued="2016-02-28 02:05:47"/>
```

Code still returns 1. What i need is to add these values from both rows so that code returns 2 in this case(there may be more rows like these and code need to check if orderState="0").

This is my code:

```
function getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id)
{
    var rows = rowset.getChildren("row");
    var level=null;
    var level2=0;
    for (var i=0;level==null && i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var row=rows[i];
        var typeIdAttr=row.getAttribute("typeID");
        if (typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==id && row.getAttribute("orderState").getValue()==0)
        {
            level2=level2 + row.getAttribute("volRemaining").getValue();

          if (i = rows.length){
            level=level2;
          }
        }
    }
    return level;
}
function TradeVolume(id) {
  //id=3389;
  var idd="orders";
  var url = "http://some.url.com";
  var document = readXml(url);
  var level = null;
var rowsets = document.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChildren("rowset");
for (var i=0;level==null && i<rowsets.length;i++)
{
    var rowset=rowsets[i];
  var typeIdAttr=rowset.getAttribute("name");
        if (typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==idd)
        {
    level=getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id);
        }
}
  if (level==null){
    level = 0
  }
  return parseFloat(level);
}
```

I've been trying to do it 3 hours and can't came up with any idea...

Edit:

Working code:

```
function getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id)
{
    var rows = rowset.getChildren("row");
    var level=0;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var row=rows[i];
        var typeIdAttr=row.getAttribute("typeID");
        if (typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==id && row.getAttribute("orderState").getValue()==0)
        {
            level=parseInt(level) + parseInt(row.getAttribute("volRemaining").getValue());
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is `if (i = rows.length)`. You are making an assignment there, where you apparently meant to test for equality. The assignment causes the loop condition to be false, so the loop terminates early.

So you could change the `if` condition to `if (i == rows.length)`. However, that test will never be true, since the loop condition includes `&& i<rows.length`. Maybe you meant to say `if (i == rows.length - 1)`, so that the body of the `if` would be executed on the last pass through the loop? But it would only happen if the *last* `row` satisfies

```
(typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==id && row.getAttribute("orderState").getValue()==0)
```

which I don't think is what you want.

Really what I expect you meant was to move the

```
      if (i == rows.length - 1) {
        level = level2;
      }
```

outside of the block of the preceding `if`. But a simpler way of doing the same thing would be to remove this if block completely, and change

```
return level;
```

to

```
return level2;
```

Comment: `var rows = rowset.getChildren("row");
    var level=0;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var row=rows[i];
        var typeIdAttr=row.getAttribute("typeID");
        if (typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==id && row.getAttribute("orderState").getValue()==0)
        {
            level=parseInt(level) + parseInt(row.getAttribute("volRemaining").getValue());
        }
    }
    return level;`

Yes, it's working with that code now, thank you